# Trying to replicate this macOS dark sierra theme

Tags: themes, gtk

so yesterday i decided to try linux because im tired of the uglyness of windows and because i wanted to get the closest to [this look](https://venganzarte.deviantart.com/art/Elementary-Os-Sierra-Dark-Mod-660033561) but [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaVIE.jpg) its what i got so far.

i dont know what to do to be honest. ive been following tutorials and everything but it just doesnt look right, even the file explorer looks different.

also the dock on the bottom is dockx but i like it like that, the one on the right is plank and ill remove it later.

if you know how to replicate the one on deviantart please let me know. thanks.

Comment: What do you think is missing from the theme i posted previously?

Answer (score 1):

How about this? [Elementary OSX](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TVOKt5NhFnnj1U8XItzjvrzlos64Mo-Y/view)
Just follow instructions and copy folders to their respective places. It looks gorgeous. Icons, GTK and Plank themes.